# How to create a "glossy text" effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, effects

I need to transform my PSD logo to Illustrator, so I will re-design it there. The purpose of it is that I will print it on business cards.

On Photoshop using the Marquee Tool I create a white Elliptical and then holding <kbd>Control</kbd> I click on the text layer, select inverse and clear.

What is this effect called, and how can I achieve it in Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a tutorial?
How about this:

1. Write out your text in your desired font.
2. Create a white oval on top of your text
3. Lower the opacity on the white oval (Window >> Transparency)
4. Select the text, right-click it and "Create outlines"
5. Select the text and the oval, now go to the pathfinder window (Window >> Pathfinder)
6. Select "Trim"
7. Select the Direct Selection Tool (A) and click on the non-overlapping part of the oval
8. Delete it.
9. You're done!

My result:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

For a crisper and smoother result:

1. Write out your text in your desired font.
2. Create a white oval on top of your text
3. Lower the opacity on the white oval (Window >> Transparency)
4. Select the text, and copy it to your clipboard
5. Select both items, right click and select "Make Clipping Mask"
6. Paste in place (Ctrl + shift + v)
7. Then move the text behind the clipping mask

Comment: Oh thank you. I am not very familiar with AI. My question is why does the end of the elliptical looks kind of too sharp ?

Comment: I edited my post to provide a crisper/smoother solution. I'm not 100% familiar with Illustrator either but these are two real quick methods. The clipping mask will keep the image looking smooth though!

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

- set the type
- convert to OUTLINES
- UNION (to make it one object)
- draw an elipse and place it on top
- Select the elipse and the logo below
- use one of the PATHFINDER commands (I believe DIVIDE or DIVIDSION will do it)

That will leave you with two objects...the top part of the type (which you can then select a lighter color for) and the lower part (original color).

Comment: Really thank you for this. I have a general question. Does a printer print white colour or just ignores it? Because if it so, I will leave the oval full size. I am printing it in white business cards.

Comment: It all depends on how it's being printed. CMYK printing (process color or 'standard 4-color printing') does not have a white ink. Spot color (pantone being common) can use white. You can also mix them.